# can I "break"/"continue" in a while loop in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, while-loop

can I "break"/"continue" in a while loop in objective-c?

(or are these reserved only for for loops)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes of course you can! Give it a try!

Answer (score 19):

From [Apple's Objective-C docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html):

> Objective-C is defined as a small but powerful set of extensions to the standard ANSI C language.

So `break` and `continue` can be used wherever they are permitted in C.

- `continue` can be used in looping constructs (`for`, `while` and `do/while` loops).
- `break` can be used in those same looping constructs as well as in `switch` statements.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can. They work the same way. `break` exits the loop and `continue` goes to the beginning and checks the condition again.